GET flutter_bootstrap.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
I am trying to deploy a Flutter web app to Firebase hosting using the FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy action and the experimental webframeworks flag. Here is my GitHub workflow file:
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: stable
          flutter-version: 3.19.0
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          firebaseServiceAccount: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FLUTTER_FAST }}
          channelId: live
          projectId: flutter-fast
          target: flutter-ast-viewer
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_EXPERIMENTS: webframeworks  

Whenever this workflow runs, the web page gets updated but it's blank and the following error appears on the network tab:

GET https://flutter-ast-viewer.web.app/flutter_bootstrap.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

If I deploy the app using the command line (firebase deploy), everything works fine.
Firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "site": "flutter-ast-viewer",
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-east1"
    }
  }
}

.firebaserc
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "flutter-ast-viewer"
  }
}



I tried a bunch of other things but it seems like something gets broken in the GitHub action. Manual deploys work fine.

"error": "Must supply a "public" or "source" directory or at least one rewrite or redirect in each "hosting" config."


Error: Hosting configs should only include either "site" or "target", not both.


"error": "Can only specify "source" or "public" in a Hosting config, not both"


Error: Directory 'build/web' for Hosting does not exist.


I have the same problem, this was my solution:
On web/index.html change:
    <script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>

for
    <script src="./flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>

It's because the path is wrong. That works for me.

This gives me a new error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at flutter_bootstrap.js:1:1)

Try this, remove the web folder and then write:
flutter create --platforms web .

This is my flutter action, you can check it, be careful with the flutter versions
name: Analyze, Build and Deploy
"on":
  push:
    branches:
      - test

jobs:
  semantic-pull-request:
    name: "Semantic"
    uses: VeryGoodOpenSource/very_good_workflows/.github/workflows/semantic_pull_request.yml@v1

  build:
    name: Build
    needs: [semantic-pull-request]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name:  Git Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name:  Setup Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: "stable"
          flutter-version: 3.22.2
      - name:  Install Dependencies
        run: |
          flutter pub get
      - name: ️ Build the application
        run: flutter build web
      - name: ⬇️ Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
          path: build/web

  deploy:
    name: "Deploy"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name:  Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: ⬇️ Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
          path: build/web
      - name:  Deploy to firebase
        uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DANCE_CLUB_COMUNA_8 }}"
          channelId: test
          projectId: dance-club-comuna-8

